# Bellman-Ford ( Shortest Path) python error

Tags: python, bellman-ford

I want to add edges to the graph to find the shortest way with bellman_ford algorithm  but in this python code when I want to use  g.addEdge() it returns me this error :

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Here is the Code :

```
    
# part of cosmos by OpenGenus Foundation
from collections import defaultdict


stableCoins = ['USDT', 'USDC', 'DAI']

# Part of Cosmos by OpenGenus Foundation
class Graph:
    def __init__(self,vertices):
        self.V = vertices # # of vertices
        self.graph = []
    # add edge to graph
    def addEdge(self, u,v,w):
        self.graph.append([u,v,w])
    # print solution
    def printArr(self,dist):
        print("Vertex Distance from Source ")
        for i in range(self.V):
            print("%d -> %d" % (i,dist[i]))
    # main function for bellman ford algo. Also detects negative weight cycles
    def bellmanFord(self,src):
        # init all distances from source to all as INFINITE
        dist = [float("Inf")] * self.V
        dist[src] = 0
        # relax all edges |V|-1 times.
        for i in range(self.V - 1):
            # update dist value and parent index of adjacent values of picked vertex.
            # consider those which are still in queue.
            for u, v, w in self.graph:
                if dist[u] != float("Inf") and dist[u] + w < dist[v]:
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + w
        # check for negative weight cycles. If path obtained from above step (shortest distances)
        # is shorter, there's a cycle. So quit.
        for u, v, w in self.graph:
            if dist[u] != float("Inf") and dist[u] + w < dist[v]:
                print("Negative Cycles !")
                return
        # print distances
        self.printArr(dist)
# dry run
if __name__ == "__main__":
#     g = Graph(3)
    for i in stableCoins :
        for j in distinct_pairnames :
            for z in distinct_pairnames :
                if (df1.loc[i,j] and df1.loc[j,i] and df1.loc[j,z] and df1.loc[z,j] and df1.loc[i,z] and df1.loc[z, i]) != 1:
                    
                    g = Graph(3)
                    
                    g.addEdge(i, j, -np.log(float(df1.loc[i,j])))
                    g.addEdge(j, i, -np.log(float(df1.loc[j,i])))
                    g.addEdge(i, z, -np.log(float(df1.loc[i,z])))
                    g.addEdge(z, i, -np.log(float(df1.loc[z,i])))
                    g.addEdge(j, z, -np.log(float(df1.loc[j,z])))
                    g.addEdge(z, j, -np.log(float(df1.loc[z, j])))
                    
                g.bellmanFord(i)
```

I want to find the shortest path from the source of each index of stableCoins list
And I have to set the name of nodes as tokenNames which are listed in **distinct_pairnames**

How Can I fix it?

Comment: There are two ways to fix it: (1) use numbers to index lists; (2) use a dictionary instead of a list in order to use a string as index

Comment: Which list and which string is giving you this error? Did you expect the list to be something else? Did you expect the string to be something else?

Comment: And what do you have under the indexes i and j in loc[i,j]? Are you sure that i and j are not strings?

Comment: @mkrieger1 ---> 24         dist[src] = 0
     25         # relax all edges |V|-1 times.
     26         for i in range(self.V - 1):

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: So `dist` is a list and `src` is a string. Is that what you had intended?

Comment: @Tehnorobot They are all floats in my pandas dataframe.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes dist is a list and src is a string showing the name of stable coin which I want to add it as a name of the node! and src represents the name of node which Algorithm should start from.

Comment: in this line `for u, v, w in self.graph:` your `u` and `v` is string, so it will throw the error when you do `if dist[u] != float("Inf") and dist[u] + w < dist[v]:`

Comment: @Rizquuula the error first appears in this Line :
'''dist[src] = 0'''

Comment: hmm,  that part was ok in my test.

Comment: Try to change this `stableCoins = ['USDT', 'USDC', 'DAI']` into integer

Comment: I have 3 for loops all of which are navigate in a list of strings! @Rizquuula

Comment: It looks like you encounter this error before you call Bellman Ford.  You can probably remove that code from your question to make everything simpler to analyze, and update your question title.